# Persist entity and save it as insert into to a file

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB (2.3.4) with Hibernate JPA (2.0) to create and update an Entity (Customer). My Entity `Customer` is annotated with `@Entity` and the ID is annotated with

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "genCustomer", strategy = "increment")    
@GeneratedValue(generator = "genCustomer")`
```

My code to create and update a Customer looks like:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class HibernateCustomerTest {
private static EntityManager em;

public static void main(String[] args) {
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hsqldb-ds");
em = emf.createEntityManager();

EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();

transaction.begin();

Customer found = em.find(Customer.class, 

System.out.println(found); // null

Customer customer1 = new Customer();

em.persist(customer1);
transaction.commit();
customer1.setCompany("asdfegj");
transaction.begin();
em.merge(customer1);
transaction.commit();
customer1 = em.find(Customer.class, 1L);
System.out.println(customer1.getCompany());

em.close();
}
```

}

Actually, this works very well. The desired output is indeed `asdfegj`.

If I try to find the created entity. It always leads to null. What is missing?

I am using HSQLDB in `file mode`. with `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"  />`. +

My `persistence.xml` looks like:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="hsqldb-ds" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <description>HSQLDB Persistence Unit</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>de.example.model.Customer</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:data/rechnungen" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"  />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"
            value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

How can I create an Entity with Java Code and store the SQL of those table and other statements to the `.script` file.

To clarify my wishes:

So when I execute the code once, the table should be created (if it does not exist of course) and the Entity should be persisted and updated aswell.

When I execute the code a second time, the entity which I created in the first execution is still present.

Comment: If you are using it in file  (as opposed to in-memory) mode then obviously the saved item should still be present if everything is working as expected. Post the config.

Comment: @AlanHay I just updated my question and show the whole code. I hope it is much cleaner now. The first statement to get my customer leads to null.

Comment: your code does not compile, missing something here in the above code incomplete at this line---Customer found = em.find(Customer.class, .....?

Comment: Try an absolute path on your file system `jdbc:hsqldb:file:c:/data/rechnungen`

Comment: @javaguy You have to create the entity yourself..Customer is example of a basic entity with id and an other value (for instance company). Just create getter and setter and use the mapping I provided so far. It should work.

Comment: the problem is what is the value you are querying with which is important

Comment: @AlanHay I dont think, that the path is the problem here. I changed the path as you suggested. The directory on C was created with all the files (.script, .properties, .log, .lock and a .temp directory). The new created .script looks like my old one. It seems to be the case, that my DB still drops everything after running my main.

Comment: @javaguy I am using `em.find` with the created ID. It is the same call below in my main. And the second call (within the transaction) worked perfectly. Searching for the Customer where the ID (primary key) is 1.

Comment: Try: jdbc:hsqldb:file:c:/data/rechnungen;shutdown=true

Comment: Also, your 2nd find doesn't prove anything as entity is in 1st level cache so no trip to DB required. em.clear() before 2nd find() would trigger a DB hit.

Comment: After some testing, I realized, that I close the entity manager, but not the entity manager factory. So I added `emf.close();` after `em.close`. Now, everytime I am running the script, I got a new line `INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES(1,'asdfegj')` into my file. This is exactly what I want! Thanks guys! If you want, provide an answer with an explanation. I will surely upvote this.